# Once Operation Bloodhound ends will I still be able to level the Operation Coin?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I bought the Operation Bloodhound pass last night and I'm trying like crazy to get the gold coin instead of silver, I know I only have to get 14 stars and in total play 30 missions, currently I'm at 10 completed missions but I was wondering....

I heard that Operation Bloodhound was going to end soon and when it does, can I continue playing missions to get the silver/gold coin?

Answer (score 5):

Once an Operation ends you will have no way to upgrade your coin past whatever current rank it is, in your case it will remain at Bronze.

This is the way all previous Operations have worked.  Once the Operation had ended, whatever rank you had your coin at is the way it will remain from then on.  For example, I still have a Silver Operation Phoenix coin since I did not get to Gold, and there is no way to rank that up past Silver.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but the answer I was expecting... That means it is over and done with.. What we have is what we have. (Its end date was yesterday)

Comment: "That's so dumb! Valve needs to let me buy and sell my operation coins!"

Comment: Well, they do. If you buy older Operation Passes, you receive a Bronze coin for that peticular operation but nothing more.